# completed 401 unauthorized devise ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, permissions, http-status-code-401

I can not get create response for current_patient. Getting response 401 unauthorized. I have tried updating the ability file.

responses_controller.rb:

```
 def create
   @reply = Response.create(params[:response])
   office = ""
   if current_user
     office = current_user.office || current_user.account.offices.first
   elsif current_patient
     office = current_patient.office_id
   end

   ...........

 end
```

Ability file:

```
def patient
 can :create, Response, :patient_id => @patient.id
end
```

Response:

```
Started POST "/responses" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-20 17:35:45 -0500
 Processing by ResponsesController#create as JS
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"blah_blah_blah", "response"=>{"review_id"=>"", "date"=>"2014-11-20 17:35:40 -0500", "patient_id"=>"13", "message"=>"Howdy neighbor!"}, "commit"=>"Submit Reply"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 166ms
```

Comment: I have tried restarting the server after saving the ability file.

Comment: Add the following 2 lines to your application layout and try to create a response again. Let me know the error messages devise shows. `<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p> <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>`